# Nothing shows up in Airdrop (macOS Sierra)

Tags: airdrop

I have a problem on my Mac. About a month or so ago Airdrop just stoped working completely.  When I go to Airdrop, in Finder, no computers are listed (even in a Mac Lab with 10+ Macs all with Airdrop enabled and discoverability set to everyone).  Other devices can find these same computers. Additionally, my Mac is non discoverable on any device, even though the discoverability is set to everyone. Firewall is off and WiFi and Bluetooth are on and work without a problem. I am NOT connected to a VPN or proxy. Additionally, although possibly unrelated (if so don't answer just thought it may be related), Handoff doesn't work between with my Mac and my iPhone and my iPhone Hotspot is not shown in WiFi unless it is turned on (which is previously did before this).

**Trouble Shooting Steps already tried (non have worked):**

- `killall sharingd`
- Restart computer
- Restart in Safe Mode
- Login to different user
- Disk Utility First Aid from recovery
- Reset NVRAM
- Reset SMC
- Reinstalled macOS
- Turned on and off Airdrop discoverability
- Turned on and off WiFi & Bluetooth
- Tried on a different WiFi network
- Apple Hardware/Apple Diagnostics Test

**Relevant Specs:**

Operating System: macOS Sierra (10.12.6)

Computer type: MacBook Pro

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Have you checked https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106, especially the 'Tips for sending items' section?

Comment: @jaume  Yes. I have checked that page.